# Is Page Layout Assignment in SFDX source?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm noticing that every time I spin up a new scratch org, I lose the page layout assignments I've specified for each of my Product2 recordtypes.

Is page layout assignment something that's supposed to be included in my SFDX project source? If so, does anybody have any ideas about why that isn't being pulled down when I do a force:source:pull? And if not, has anyone come up with any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Did you pull the Profile object as well? If not, then that would be an expected behavior.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible not to. I understood that force:source:pull is going to pull all the custom metadata in a scratch org regardless of type. Is there something specific I need to do to reference specific metadata types?

Comment: @AGallinat Did you find out how to get the layout assignment metadata?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that to get layout assignment you have to specify that you want to retrieve Profile, Layout, RecordType and CustomObject at the same time. You may also want to provide your_custom_object, like this:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile,Layout,RecordType,CustomObject:your_custom_object
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, changing page layout assignments isn't detected by sfdx force:source:status or pull.
I got the whole profile metadata using

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile
```

Then snipped out everything except the layoutAssignments snippet(s) I wanted.

Comment: Any idea why both `sfdx force:source:retrieve` and `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` aren't giving me the layoutAssignments?